# How i can translate/Flip View/manager in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

i want to translate/Flip view/ manager in BlackBerry when i press Next Button or Previous Button which available in status Bar, i m attaching my screen. Does any body have idea please send me

Thanx in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When u click on your Next Prev `Button` you have to change your `Bitmapfield` image using `bitmapfield.setBitmap("your new image");`

Comment: thanx for rply but i want to translate whole layout which have images and text.

Comment: than delete old manager (vfm) and add new vfm with all content .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `net.rim.device.api.ui.extension.component.PictureScrollField` to achieve the desired effect